# 500 internal server error on POST request

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mern

I've been showing 500 internal server error for registration of user( basically I am making a login system for my webapp) there's no error on terminal

**appController.js**

```js
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import userModel from "../model/user.model.js";

export async function register(req, res) {
  try {
    const { username, password, profile, email } = req.body;

    // check existing user
    const existUsername = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      userModel.findOne({ username }, (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(new Error(err));
        }
        if (user)
          reject({
            error: "Username already in use",
          });
        resolve();
      });
    });

    // check for existing email
    const existEmail = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      userModel.findOne({ email }, (err, email) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(new Error(err));
        }
        if (email)
          reject({
            error: "Email already in use",
          });
        resolve();
      });
    });

    Promise.all([existUsername, existEmail])
      .then(() => {
        if (password) {
          const hashedPassword =
          bcrypt
            .hash(password, 10)
            .then((hashedPassword) => {
              const User = new userModel({
                username,
                password: hashedPassword,
                profile: profile || "",
                email,
              });

              //return save result as a response
              User.save()
                .then((result) =>
                  res.status(201).send({ msg: "User Registered Successfully" })
                )

                .catch((err) =>
                  res.status(500).send(err + "inside saving process")
                );
            })
            .catch((err) => {
              return res.status(500).send({
                error: "Enable to hash password",
              });
            });
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        return res.status(500).send(err);
      });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).send(error);
  }
}
```

**user.model.js**

```js
import mongoose from "mongoose";

export const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "please provide unique Username"],
    unique: [true, "username already exists"],
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "please provide a password"],
    unique: false,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "please provide a unique email address"],
    unique: true,
  },
  firstName: { type: String },
  lastName: { type: String },
  mobile: { type: Number },
  address: { type: String },
  profile: { type: String },
});

export default mongoose.model.Users || mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

**Server.js**

```js
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import morgan from "morgan";
import connect from "./mongoConnect.js";
import router from "./routes/route.js";

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(morgan("tiny")); // HTTP request logger middleware for node.js
app.disable("x-powered-by");
app.use("/api", router); // now all routes will goes by prefix '''/api'''

const PORT = 8080 || process.env.PORT;

// HTTP get request
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.status(201).json({ msg: "Home GET request success" });
});

// start server only when we have valid connection
connect()
  .then(() => {
    try {
      // start server
      app.listen(PORT, () => {
        console.log(`app running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      console.log("can't connect to the server");
    }
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log(e + "occured Invalid database connection");
  });
```

**mongoConnect.js**

```js
import mongoose from "mongoose";

import { MongoMemoryServer } from "mongodb-memory-server";

async function connect() {
  // to create new mongoDB server instance whenever you start server
  const mongod = await MongoMemoryServer.create();
  const getURI = mongod.getUri(); // returns MongoDB URL

  mongoose.set("strictQuery", true);
  const db = await mongoose.connect(getURI);
  console.log("Database connected!!!");
  return db;
}

export default connect;
```

**route.js**

```js
import { Router } from "express";
// import all controllers
import * as controller from "../controller/appController.js";

const router = Router();

// POST requests
router.route("/register").post(controller.register);
```

// just showing what is used till now but I have made all routes as well as controller functions

I tried all the basic syntax errors that can occurs every time. also callback functions error handling but there' nothing I found till now

Comment: Please share the error message too

Comment: That's the problem brother there's nothing showing in the terminal except request call "POST /api/register 500 2 - 4.131 ms".. 500 internal server error showing in postman and ThunderClient VSCode extention.

Comment: First which version of Mongoose you use ? if you use 7.0+ than you should use the syntax async/ await and not with Promise and callback.

Answer (score 0):

Remove new Promise to work properly

```
const existUsername = (() => {
  userModel.findOne({ username }, (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      (new Error(err));
    }
    if (user)
      ({
        error: "Username already in use",
      });
    
  });
});

// check for existing email
const existEmail = (() => {
  userModel.findOne({ email }, (err, email) => {
    if (err) {
      (new Error(err));
    }
    if (email)
      ({
        error: "Email already in use",
      });
    
  });
});
```